# Avro messages within Avro messages: reasonable?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I want to do something crazy with Kafka and avro.  Someone talk me off the ledge:

```
record Bundle {
   string key;
   array<bytes> msgs;
}
```

Producers individually serialize a bunch of messages that share a key, then serialize a bundle and post to a topic.

A generic Flattener service is configured by startup parameters to listen to 1...n kafka topics containing bundles, then blindly forward the bundled messages to configured output topics one at a time.  (Blindly meaning it takes the bytes from the array and puts them on the wire.)

Use case:

I have services that respond to small operations (update record, delete record, etc).  At times, I want batches of ops that need to be gauranteed not to be interleaved with other ops for the same key.

To accomplish this, my thought was to position a Flattener in front of each of the services in question.  Normal, one-off commands get stored in 1-item bundles, true batchs are bundled into bigger ones.

I don't use a specific field type for the inner messages, because I'd like to be able to re-use Flattener all over the place

Does this make any sense at all?  Potential drawbacks?

EDIT:

Each instance of the Flattener service would only be delivering message of types known to the ultimate consumers with schema_ids embedded in them.

The only reason array is not an array of a specific type is that I'd like to be able to re-use Flattener unchanged in front of multiple different services (just started with different environment variables / command line parameters).

Comment: Potential drawback: Schema evolution within that inner field cannot be validated by a consumer.

Comment: @cricket_007 why not?  Not by the flattener certainly, but wouldn't end consumer be able to do all the normal stuff?  Or is that the issue -- that it could pass through a hop without validation?

Comment: The consumer has no idea the `msgs` should be Avro. You would need to ship your deserializer as part of every consumer class

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm confused.  The ultimate consumer doesn't read the msgs array.  The Flattener picks each msg from the the array and sticks it into a second topic for ultimate consumer.   The Flattener might be repeating a message that won't properly deserialize, but that's none of its concern.

Comment: Considering I cannot see this "Flattener" class, I guess I don't understand it's purpose, then. In the long run, you're sending bytes within Avro. If those bytes happen to be Avro, then fine, but you'd be paying a penalty in network bandwidth by shipping the necessary schema along with that data as compared to using a Schema Registry.

Comment: So events need to processed one at a time.  The only reason to bundle them at all is that in some cases, a group of events cannot be interleaved with other events.  This two-stage approach accomplishes that. (Delivers bundle of 1-n msgs to topic 1, process topic1 in order, emitting contents of bundle as 1..n messages in topic2, consumer reads topic 2.) I don't follow why schema would need to be passed around.  The serialized msgs wouldn't reference the registry schema? I'm not very familiar with how registry schemas work.

Comment: If you're not using a registry, then you need a schema to deserialize the Avro message. That's just how Avro works. The registry is not required. But anyway, is Avro really required? Move the `String key` over to the Kafka message key, then you just have a plain `byte[]` as the value... And you can write any serializer/deserializer you want, doing whatever logic is done by this Flatten thing.

Comment: Would the [transactional producers](https://www.confluent.io/blog/transactions-apache-kafka/) added in Kafka 0.11 do what you need, without embedding Avro in Avro?  (N.B. I can't easily find a clear statement that different transactions' messages won't be interleaved.)

Comment: @cricket_007 We're moving to a registry.  In v1, the target consumer would have the schema.  In v2, it would pull the schema from the registry using the schema_id.  I'd like to use  Avro because it's a structured complex data type and I want to deserialize it to a class so I can deal with it safely in my program.   It seems like there's some confusion about Flattener.  It does absolutely nothing that I haven't explained here.  Based on its runtime params, it reads bundles from one topic, then emits individual messages from the bundles onto output topics.

Comment: @DavidMaze interesting, I'll give it a try!

Comment: You can still use Avro as the value bytes. My only suggestion was that you don't need to "embed" things as Kafka already has (key, value) as separate fields in the messages.

Comment: @cricket_007 oh ok I didn't think about that :facepalm:.  Makes sense thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to move my comment to an answer because I think it's reasonable to "talk you off the ledge" ;)

If you set up a `Producer<String, GenericRecord>` (change the Avro class as you wish), you already have a String key and Avro bytes as the value. This way, you won't need to embed anything